# Logic within python and Tkinter: how to make a window run endlessly

Tags: python, tkinter, logic

I am currently attempting to build a battleship game using Tkinter. I am at an impass however, as I am not able to make the program properly "wait" for an answer and show the Tkinter window.
My idea was that whenever a submit button would be pressed, a value would be set to true. As long as that value was false, then the program would just loop through a while loop. When this value is triggered, the next set of actions would be given along with setting that value back to false, and waiting for it to be true once more. Here is the code:

```
from Tkinter import *

import time


class Application(Frame):

    def __init__(self,master):
        self.user = False
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.launch()
        self.master = master
        self.shiplist = []

        self.board = [
        ["A",1],["B",1],["C",1],["D",1],["E",1],["F",1],["G",1],["H",1],["I",1],["J",1],
        ["A",2],["B",2],["C",2],["D",2],["E",2],["F",2],["G",2],["H",2],["I",2],["J",2],
        ["A",3],["B",3],["C",3],["D",3],["E",3],["F",3],["G",3],["H",3],["I",3],["J",3],
        ["A",4],["B",4],["C",4],["D",4],["E",4],["F",4],["G",4],["H",4],["I",4],["J",4],
        ["A",5],["B",5],["C",5],["D",5],["E",5],["F",5],["G",5],["H",5],["I",5],["J",5],
        ["A",6],["B",6],["C",6],["D",6],["E",6],["F",6],["G",6],["H",6],["I",6],["J",6],
        ["A",7],["B",7],["C",7],["D",7],["E",7],["F",7],["G",7],["H",7],["I",7],["J",7],
        ["A",8],["B",8],["C",8],["D",8],["E",8],["F",8],["G",8],["H",8],["I",8],["J",8],
        ["A",9],["B",9],["C",9],["D",9],["E",9],["F",9],["G",9],["H",9],["I",9],["J",9],
        ["A",10],["B",10],["C",10],["D",10],["E",10],["F",10],["G",10],["H",10],["I",10],["J",10],
        ]
        self.letters = [["A",1],["B",2],["C",3],["D",4],["E",5],["F",6],["G",7],["H",8],["I",9],["J",10]]
    def launch(self):
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        Label(self, text="Your Board").grid(sticky=W,row = 0, column = 0)
        Label(self, text="Enemy Board").grid(sticky=W, row = 0,column = 2)

        canvas1 = Canvas(self)
        canvas1.create_rectangle(2,2,250,250,outline= "black",fill = "white")
        canvas1.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, rowspan=2)

        canvas2 = Canvas(self)
        canvas2.create_rectangle(2,2,250,250,outline= "black",fill = "white")
        canvas2.grid(row=1, column=2, columnspan=2, rowspan=2)

        self.actionLabel = Label(self,text = "Currently Placing:")
        self.actionLabel.grid(row = 3,column= 0,sticky = W)

        self.infoLabel1 = Label(self,text ="")
        self.infoLabel1.grid(row = 4,column = 0)

        self.infoLabel2 = Label(self,text = "")
        self.infoLabel2.grid(row=5,column=0)

        self.userinput = Entry(self,text = "Write here")
        self.userinput.grid(row=6,column=0)

        Button(self,text = "Submit",command = self.action).grid(row = 6,column = 1,sticky = W)

        self.errorlabel = Label(self,text = "")
        self.errorlabel.grid(row=7,column=0)
        self.request_ships()
    def action(self):
        value = self.userinput.get()
        self.user = True
        print "action successful"
    def request_ship(self,allegiance,name,size):
        print allegiance,name,size
        ship = [name,size]
        error = False
        if allegiance == "player":
            print "here"
            while error == False:
                self.user = False
                text1 =  name + "Size: "+ str(size) + " cells."
                self.infoLabel1.configure(text = text1)
                self.infoLabel2.configure(text = "Would you like for your ship to be vertical or horizontal? v/h:")
                if self.user == True:    
                    if value != "vertical" and value != "horizontal" and value != "h" and value != "v":
                        self.errorlabel.configure(text = "Error! Incorrect Format!")
                        error = False
                    else:
                        self.user = False
                        if value == "h":
                            ship += value
                            self.infoLabel2.configure(text = "Please enter the leftmost coordinate of where you want to place your ship:")
                            if self.user== True:
                                if len(value) > 1 and len(value) <= 3 and (value[0] == "A"
                                or value[0] == "B" or value[0] == "C" or value[0] == "D"
                                or value[0] == "E" or value[0] == "F" or value[0] == "G"
                                or value[0] == "H" or value[0] == "I" or value[0] == "J") and (value[1] == "1"
                                or value[1] == "2" or value[1] == "3" or value[1] == "4"
                                or value[1] == "5" or value[1] == "6" or value[1] == "7"
                                or value[1] == "8" or value[1] == "9" or value[1] == "10"):
                                    for i in range(len(self.board)):
                                        if self.board[i][0] == value[0] and self.board[i][0] == value[1:]:
                                            num = 0
                                            for i in size:
                                                coord+= i + num
                                                num += 1
        print ship
    def request_ships(self):
        print "request ships works"
        self.request_ship("player","Aircraft Carrier",5)

    def grid(self,gridinfo,shipinfo):
        coord = 0
        cellnum = 0
        for number in range(100):

            cell = Canvas(self)
            for ship in shipinfo:
               ## if #####
                print "tt"
            cell.create_rectangle(coord,coord,25,25,outline="black",fill=color)

def main():

    root = Tk()
    app = Application(root)
    app.geometry = ("1000x1000")
    root.title("Battleship")
    root.mainloop()



main()
```

The issue however, is that the window never appears when the request_ships function is loading, as it's endlessly going in a while loop. Any tips on how to fix this?

Comment: Some meta tips: 1) search for tkinter input background sort of keywords.  Quite a few useful approaches already described in answers.   2) http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some things to look into: you have `while error == False`, but the only reference to `error` within the loop is to assign `False` to it. In the loop, you assign `self.user = False`, but then almost everything in the loop relies on getting into `if self.user == True`. You assign `self.userinput.get()` to the *local* variable `value` rather than to an instance variable. You should make more use of the `in` operator to avoid making dozens of separate comparisons. You were only checking `value[1]` in the large `if` statement within `if self.user == True`. Instead of checking whether a value is equal to `True` or `False`, you can just refer to that value, e.g. `if self.user:`, because another way to express `True == True` is simply `True` (unless that variable has an uncertain type and you really do need to check whether it's `True` or, say, a non-empty string). You're checking what's in the `Entry` box before it's actually ready - you should put `request_ships()` into some `Button`'s command, or at least wait a second with `after()`. You're checking if `self.board[i][0]` is equal to both `value[0]` and `value[1]`, which will only be true if the user enters something invalid like `AA`. If we fix that to also check `self.board[i][1]`, it still won't work because everything in an `Entry` widget is a string, which must be converted to an `int`. You cannot concatenate a string onto a `list` - use `append()`. Checking for vertical/horizontal, location, etc., one after the other, from a single function will run into issues, because you never wait for the user to enter a different value.

Here's a sample of `request_ship()` with a few of these changes implemented so you can get an idea of where to go:

```
def request_ship(self,allegiance,name,size):
    print allegiance,name,size
    ship = [name,size]
    error = True
    if allegiance == "player":
        print "here"
        text1 =  name + "Size: "+ str(size) + " cells."
        self.infoLabel1.configure(text = text1)
        self.infoLabel2.configure(text = "Would you like for your ship to be vertical or horizontal? v/h:")
        if self.user:    
            if self.value not in ("vertical", "horizontal", "h", "v"):
                self.errorlabel.configure(text = "Error! Incorrect Format!")
            else:
                self.user = False
                if self.value == "h":
                    ship.append(self.value)
                    self.infoLabel2.configure(text = "Please enter the leftmost coordinate of where you want to place your ship:")
                    if self.user:
                        try:
                            v1 = int(self.value[1:])
                        except ValueError:
                            pass
                        if 1 < len(self.value) <= 3 and (self.value[0] in "ABCDEFGHIJ") and (v1 in range(1,11)):
                            for i in range(len(self.board)):
                                if self.board[i][0] == self.value[0] and self.board[i][1] == v1:
                                    num = 0
                                    for i in size:
                                        coord+= i + num
                                        num += 1
            self.user = False
```

Please note that the above code is neither complete nor a drop-in replacement to make your program work. Your code will need some serious restructuring to deal with being a GUI program vs a command-line program.

Comment: I can't vote, so that wasn't me nor can I give you an upvote. sorry :l